# Main components in design/implementing a mail.app client for Mac OS X? Any Advice?

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix

I was asked for a quick research on main required components/technologies for coding a new(separate) mail.app client on Mac OS X (using Cocoa). I'm just focusing to the component(s) that interact with Servers to pulling data from SMTP/IMAp/POP3 server, or send the mail to the servers.

Does anyone know if I create a daemon for pulling the data from server would be the right and efficient approach for keeping the list updated? How do I manage the frequency of pulling data from it (need a timer)? Do I need to look into Apple Push Notification Server too?

What would be the other major component/design for communication between mail.app and server  in this application?

Comment: Mail.app *is* a mail client. Are you trying to create a separate mail client, or some sort of program that will interact with Apple's Mail.app application? If the former, your question boils down to "how do I write an e-mail client?" and is likely to be considered too broad.

Comment: a separate(new) mail client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if I create a daemon for pulling the data from server
>   would be the right and efficient approach for keeping the list
>   updated?

That's one way that you could support keeping mail up to date on the client machine even when your mail application itself isn't running. On the other hand, one wonders why the user would need their mail updated if they can't see it because they're not using the mail application.

> How do I manage the frequency of pulling data from it (need a timer)?

How do you want it to be managed? Many mail clients let the user decide how often to check for new e-mail, and that seems like a reasonable way to proceed.

> Do I need to look into Apple Push Notification Server too?

Apple's mail client is integrated into Apple's own iCloud (formerly ".me", formerly ".mac") system so that messages sent to an address @icloud.net trigger a push notification so that users see an updated icon badge with the number of unread messages. You won't be able to do that unless you control both the client application and the mail server. If you do, then sure, APNS is a reasonable way to update the client. If you're just pulling mail from a standard POP or IMAP server, APNS won't do much for you.

Comment: For the time the mail client is not running, I can terminate that daemon?what would be the better way to keep the list update?(other than using a daemon)

Comment: I think you're putting the cart ahead of the horse. Writing a useful mail client isn't as simple as it sounds; I'd focus first on getting a client running with a button that the user can push to fetch new mail. Once you've got that done, you can worry about how best to automatically fetch mail.